# Execute the loop until the condition met

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I need this code to execute the loop until I get result 1. I want to make this code to calculate depending on the **inputNum** if **inputNum** is even, the **inputNum** is divided by 2 and if the **inputNum** is odd, then multiple by 3 and plus one. I have done this so far but I have lost how to *loop* this **function** the *condition* is until I get result 1 as final. I really need your help Please teach me

```
const inputNum = 5;

let i = inputNum;

while (i == 1) {
  calculateNum();
}

function calculateNum() {
  if (inputNum % 2 == 0) {
    console.log('Input number : ' + inputNum + ' (even number!)');
    let result = inputNum / 2;
    console.log('Result: ' + result);
  } else {
    console.log('Input number : ' + inputNum + ' (odd number!)');
    let result = inputNum * 3 + 1;
    console.log('Result: ' + result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
const inputNum = 5;

let i = inputNum;

while (i !== 1) {
  calculateNum();
}

function calculateNum() {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    console.log("Input number : " + i + " (even number!)");
    i = i / 2;
    console.log("Result: " + i);
  } else {
    console.log("Input number : " + i + " (odd number!)");
    i = i * 3 + 1;
    console.log("Result: " + i);
  }
}
```

result:

```
Input number : 5 (odd number!)
Result: 16
Input number : 16 (even number!)
Result: 8
Input number : 8 (even number!)
Result: 4
Input number : 4 (even number!)
Result: 2
Input number : 2 (even number!)
Result: 1
```

EDIT:

So the main issue with your code is that you don't update the value of `i`, so actually you have an endless loop.

Instead of using the result, update the value of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the while loop in your function.

```
let inputNum = 5;

function calculateNum(inputNum) {
  while(inputNum !== 1) {
    if (inputNum % 2 == 0) {
      console.log('Input number : ' + inputNum + ' (even number!)');
      inputNum = inputNum / 2;
      console.log('Result: ' + inputNum);
    } else {
      console.log('Input number : ' + inputNum + ' (odd number!)');
      inputNum = inputNum * 3 + 1;
      console.log('Result: ' + inputNum);
    }
  }
  return inputNum
}

calculateNum(inputNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a result from calculateNum:

```
function calculateNum() {
  if (inputNum % 2 == 0) {
    console.log('Input number : ' + inputNum + ' (even number!)');
    let result = inputNum / 2;
    console.log('Result: ' + result);
    return result;
  } else {
    console.log('Input number : ' + inputNum + ' (odd number!)');
    let result = inputNum * 3 + 1;
    console.log('Result: ' + result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Then in your loop capture (and test) the result:

```
while (i != 1) {
  i = calculateNum();
}
```